# Getting a variable from the input and displaying it again

Tags: javascript

helo guys I am writing ajava Script that have an input box to allow the user enter a value and I want to show him again what he enterd with in that page to ensure that he will see what he is enterd for example

```
<input id="userName" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" name="userName">
I have these input box and I want get this value and display it again in alabel bellow
<label id="user_label" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"></label>
```

and I write the following JS

```
user_Name=getElementById('userName');
document.getElementById('user_label').innerHTML=user_Name;
```

and these displays the string userName not the string value init what can I do

Answer (score 0):

Just grab the value from the HTML element instead...

```
var user_Name = document.getElementById('userName').value;
document.getElementById('user_label').innerHTML = user_Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var user_Name=getElementById('userName');
document.getElementById('user_label').innerHTML=user_Name.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is call your code whenever the input field is changed.

```
<input id="userName" type="text" name="userName" onKeyUp="update()">
```

And in JS:

```
function update() {
   var user_Name=document.getElementById('userName').value;
   document.getElementById('user_label').innerHTML=user_Name;
}
```

Also you need to refer to the .value of the input element to get its value.

Here is a Pen:
http://codepen.io/calvinclaus/pen/EKBvBz?editors=1011